# Member Status command shows number of people streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I made a member status command for my discord bot. Here is my code:

```js
const { stripIndent } = require('common-tags');
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith("+members")) {
        const members = message.guild.members.cache.array();
        const online = members.filter((m) => m.presence.status === 'online').length;
        const offline = members.filter((m) => m.presence.status === 'offline').length;
        const dnd = members.filter((m) => m.presence.status === 'dnd').length;
        const afk = members.filter((m) => m.presence.status === 'idle').length;
        const streaming = members.filter((m) => m.presence.status === 'streaming').length;
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`Member Status [${message.guild.members.cache.size}]`)
            .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription(stripIndent`
           **Online:** \`${online}\` members
             **Busy:** \`${dnd}\` members
            **AFK:** \`${afk}\` members
             **Offline:** \`${offline}\` members
             **Streaming:** \`${streaming}\` members
          `)
            .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setTimestamp()
            .setColor(message.guild.me.displayHexColor);
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});
```

I want the number the number of people who are streaming to be shown too. However even when there are users who are streaming my bot shows 0 at the Streaming People count. Anyway to fix this out?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PresenceStatus](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PresenceStatus) via `member.presence.status` can only be `online`, `idle`, `offline` or `dnd`.

To check if a user is streaming, you need to use the [activities of a Presence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=activities).

`member.presence.activities` returns an `Array<Activity>`. You can use the [ActivityType](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType) to check if a member is streaming.

To put it all together:

```js
member.presence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            // member is currently streaming
        }
});
```